# Create a server farm (aka App Service Plan) from the command line

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

We are creating an Azure Web App using the command line interface. How do we create a server farm from the CLI? This is what we have already done.

```
azure login
azure group create MyGroup "West US"
azure webapp create -g MyGroup -n MyApp -l "West US"
```

The error is:

> parameters.webSite.properties.serverFarm cannot be null.

How do we create a server farm from the CLI? Here are some things we have tried.

```
azure resource create -g MyGroup -n MyFarm 
    -r "Microsoft.Web/ServerFarms" -l "West US" -o "2015-08-01" 
    -p "{ `"SKU`": `"`" }"
```

We have not been able to determine how to set the `-p` value with an appropriate JSON object. Azure complains about unexpected characters. None of these work.

```
-p "{ sku: "" }"          // Unexpected token s
-p "{ 'sku': "" }"        // Unexpected token '
-p "{ \'sku\' : \'\' }"   // uUnexpected token \
-p "{ `'sku`' : `'`' }"   // uUnexpected token '
-p "{ `"sku`" : `"`" }"   // Unexpected token s
-p "{\"sku\":{\"tier\": \"Standard\"}}"    // SKU cannot be null.
```

`-p` is supposed to be "a JSON-formatted string containing properties". What do they mean by that?

Comment: is there a command to create "Hosting Service" ? server farm also known as hosting service.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you intend to use api-version `2015-08-01`

```
azure resource create MyGroup MyFarm "Microsoft.Web/ServerFarms" 
  -l "West US" -o "2015-08-01" 
  -p "{\"sku\":{\"tier\": \"Standard\", \"name\": \"S1\"}, \"properties\": {\"numberOfWorkers\": 1, \"workerSize\": 0}"
```

Comment: When executing that command, I get a "The parameter SKU cannot be null." error message.

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback. I will try my solution again

Answer (score 0):

This works with -apiVersion [`2015-06-01`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2014-06-01/Microsoft.Web.json) though I haven't figured out the schema change for [`2015-08-01`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2015-08-01/Microsoft.Web.json).

```
azure resource create MyGroup MyFarm "Microsoft.Web/ServerFarms" 
  -l "West US" -o "2015-06-01" 
  -p "{\"sku\":{\"tier\": \"Standard\"},\"numberOfWorkers\":1,\"workerSize\": \"Small\"}"
```

Comment: You can reference the schema for "2015-08-01" api version at this link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2015-08-01/Microsoft.Web.json